# ¿Por qué parte del componente Reajct no se muestra en algunos navegadores?

Tags: reactjs, componentes

Soy nuevo usando React y estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto. Resulta que en mi PC todo funciona como debe ser, pero cuando subo el proyecto a internet y lo ejecuto en algunos navegadores no se muestran parte de los componentes, me he dado cuenta que son navegadores desactualizados, mientras estén actualizados todo funciona bien. He aqui parte del proyecto; el problema radica en que del componente WinRatioComponent solo se muestra esta parte ¨Win ratio¨ y el componente  LoadingComponent , lo demas nunca lo llega a mostrar. Alguna idea de por qué este comportamiento?

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { WinRatioComponent } from "./WinRatioComponent";


export const AccountInformation = () => {
    const [dataMetaApi, setDataMetaApi] = useState(null)
    const [dataGraf, setDataGraf] = useState([['Date','Balance']])
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const _id = '....'
    const cargardatametaapi = async () => {        
        try {
            const url = `https://metastats-api-v1.new-york.agiliumtrade.ai/users/current/accounts/${_id}/metrics`
            const response = await fetch(url)
            const dataresponse = await response.json()
            setDataMetaApi(dataresponse)  
            setDataGraf(dataresponse.metrics.dailyGrowth)          
            dataresponse.metrics.dailyGrowth.map(item => {                
                dataGraf.push([item.date, item.balance])                           
            })
            setDataGraf(dataGraf)  
            setIsLoading(false)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        cargardatametaapi()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="container">

            <WinRatioComponent  isLoading={isLoading} data ={dataMetaApi}/>
            

          
        </div>
    )
}





import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";
import '../styles/WinRatio.css'
import { LoadingComponent } from "./loadingComponent";

export const WinRatioComponent = ({ isLoading, data }) => {
  const optionsPieChart = {
    pieHole: 0.4,
    is3D: false,
  };

  return (
    <div className="container grafico">
      <h4><strong>Win ratio</strong></h4>
      {isLoading
        ? <LoadingComponent />
        : data
          && <Chart
          chartType="PieChart"
          data={[
            ['Result', '%'],
            ['Win', data.metrics.wonTrades],
            ['Lost', data.metrics.lostTrades],
          ]}
          options={optionsPieChart}
          width="100%"
          height="400px"
          legendToggle
        />
      }

    </div>

  )
}
```

Comment: y de donde obtienes ese 'winRatioComponent'? nunca había odio hablar de una librería así,,,

Comment: es un componente propio

Comment: pues enseñalo a los demas entonces, sino se hace imposible de testear

Comment: esta abajo, el primer componente es por decirlo el principal y ahi se llama a ese componente